# How can you 'NOT' allow NON-spaces in a regex?

Tags: regex, validation

I'm currently busy with a Dutch telephonenumber validation, which only allows the following patterns:

> Note: n stands for number.
>
> ```
> nn-123
> nn-12345678
>
> nnn-1234567
>
> nnnn-1234
> nnnn-123456
> nnnn-1234567
> ```
>
> Note: A Space instead of a Dash is also allowed.

The problem is that my Regular Expression also allows a NON-Space, but it should only allow a Dash or a Space.

Here's my regex code so far:

```
 /^([0-9]{3}[- ]?([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{7})|[0-9]{2}[- ]?([0-9]{3}|[0-9]{8})|[0-9]{4}[- ]?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7})|[0-9]{3}[- ]?([0-9]{7}))$
```

EDIT: To clear things up, here's an example to my problem:

Example of some phone numbers that are allowed:

```
  06-12345678
  0800 1234
  425-1234567
```

Example of a phone number that isn’t allowed:

```
  1234567890 (My regex sadly allows this number)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `libphonenumber` instead of DIY?

Comment: @Dai No I haven't, I didn't know what it was before you told me. The thing is, is that my regex code only has one bug that I need to fix. I think it would be a waste if I throw this code away for only a bug, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: why nnn and then number literals on the other side ?

Comment: You have a space after the dash in this section: "[- ]". Just remove that space. You actually don't need the character class, just put the dash.

Comment: @pvsr I've added an example to clear things up

Comment: @sorayadragon The space is also allowed

Comment: @Sergio Ah sorry, I misread, I thought the space was not allowed.

Comment: @Sergio is the answer I provided below not what you expect?

Comment: I'm confused, you state that `nn-12345678` is allowed so shouldn't `-06-12345678` be invalid? Is the leading dash optional or required?

Comment: The topic of this question is very confusing

Comment: @prsvr I didn’t get it to work with my Regex, but thanks for your help

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the first dash is meant to mark the lines as list items, my apology if that made the explanation confusing, my bad I’ll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match those formats you might use alternations `|` and use the character class `[- ]` but not make it optional.

In parts

```
^(?:[0-9]{2}[- ](?:[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{3})|[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{7}|[0-9]{4}[ -](?:[0-9]{6,7}|[0-9]{4}))$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]{2}[- ]` Match 2 digits and space or hyphen
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[0-9]{8}` Match 8 digits
    - `|` Or
    - `[0-9]{3}` Match 3 digits
  - `)` Close group
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{7}` Match 3 digits, space or hyphen and 7 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]{4}[ -]` Match 4 digits and either space or hyphen
  - `(?:`

    - `[0-9]{6,7}` Match 6-7 digits
    - `|` Or
    - `[0-9]{4}` Match 4 digits
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zRmLcP/1)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

`\d{2,4}[-, \s]\d{3,}`

Not really sure what specifics of your requirement are, but this will work in the following way:

- it will match between 2 and 4 digit characters
- previously matched digit characters must be followed by either a dash or a spacing character
- the dash or the spacing character must be followed by at least 3 digit characters

If this doesn't work for you then provide all the specific constraints/requirements you need.

Edit, regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/uVwAK1/1

I've replaced "n" characters with number 1.